# parse.com how to set verbose logging

Tags: android, parse-platform

Am trying to trace errors pertaining to parse push notifications on android devices, came across a suggestion about verbose logging. How do you turn on verbose logging for the parse backend service for android apps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    Parse.setLogLevel(Parse.LOG_LEVEL_VERBOSE);
```